# Get random custom posts from a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, get-posts

I created a custom post type named `predic`, I’m trying to get within one of this post other four random posts from the same custom post type. I used this code, but I keep getting the same post I’m in 4 times.

```
<ul>
<?php
$rand_posts = get_posts('numberposts=4&orderby=rand');
foreach( $rand_posts as $post ) :
?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to include `setup_postdata($post);` in your foreach line. Here's some great demo code from the codex, adopted to fit your query:

```
<ul>
<?php
global $post;
$tmp_post = $post;
$myposts = get_posts( 'post_type=predic&numberposts=4&orderby=rand' );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php $post = $tmp_post; ?>
</ul>
```

Note that we're also resetting $post back to the current post, so we don't break other functionality.

Comment: I had to add a definition of te post type and it worked like a charm, thanks for your help <ul>
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'predicadores', 'numberposts' => 4, 'orderby' => 'rand'); 
$tmp_post = $post;
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php $post = $tmp_post; ?>
</ul>

Comment: Great! I updated my answer to avoid confusion for future visitors.